# JQuery parent selector to find step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-steps

I am using a jquery steps control. The form is posted in the `onFinished()` event with an Ajax request being fired off. From the server I return the following if any validation errors occur:

```
{
    "ErrorMessages": 
        [{
            "PropertyName":"Complainant.Address.StreetName",
            "ErrorMessage":"The complainant street name is required."
        },
        {
            "PropertyName":"Complainant.Address.Suburb",
            "ErrorMessage":"The complainant suburb is required."
        }]
}
```

Next in jQuery I find the appropriate span element (that is created with the ASP.NET MVC's `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`) and give it the provided validation message:

```
if (response.ErrorMessages != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.ErrorMessages.length; i++) {
        var validationSpan = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + response.ErrorMessages[i].PropertyName + "'");
        validationSpan.html(response.ErrorMessages[i].ErrorMessage);
        validationSpan.removeClass("field-validation-valid");
        validationSpan.addClass("field-validation-error");
    }
}
```

Next step is to set the Jquery step header as red in order to show that a validation error has occurred on that step. This part is not working:

```
var section = validationSpan.parent(".step-div");
$("#steps-uid-0-t-" + section.attr("step")).css("background", "#ff3111");
```

I have the following html structure:

```
<div>
    <h1>Complaint details</h1>
    <section>
        <div class="step-div" step="0">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Complainant.Address.StreetName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Complainant.Address.StreetName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Complainant.Address.StreetName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<div>
```

The part that seems to not be working:

```
var section = validationSpan.parent(".step-div");
```

This should give me the `<div>` that's directly inside the `<section>`, but it doesn't seem to. If I log this `section` variable I get the following:

```
{ length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument ? 134 }
```

[image]

The rendered `<a>` element that I want to apply the style to looks like this (depending on which step it is):

Step 1:

```
<a id="steps-uid-0-t-0" href="#steps-uid-0-h-0" aria-controls="steps-uid-0-p-0"><span class="number">1.</span> Complainant details</a>
```

Step 2:

```
<a id="steps-uid-0-t-1" href="#steps-uid-0-h-1" aria-controls="steps-uid-0-p-1"><span class="number">2.</span> Complaint details</a>
```

Comment: `var section = validationSpan.closest(".step-div");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.parents()` instead of `.parent()`. Better yet, try the `.closest()`.

`.parents()` gets all the ancestors that match the given selector.

`.parent()` looks up only on the direct parent.

`.closest()` looks up element itself and the ancestors to return the first one that matches the given selector.